# How to add newrelic jar as javaagent in jvm argument in gradle spring boot project

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, newrelic, jvm-arguments

I have a spring boot gradle project in which i need to confiugure NewRelic. As of now i have checked i manually setting the javagent in runconfiguration under jvm arguments and it's working.

Now i am looking out the way to configure the it in gradle. I know that we can set jvm argument as follows:-

```
bootRun {
jvmArgs = ["-Dlog.directory=.", "-Dlog.media=STDOUT", "-javaagent:$rootDir/gradle/newrelic.jar"]
}
```

but it;s not picking the newrelic.jar.

Can anybody help me with this. What's wrong i am doing here. Where i need to put downloaded newrelic.jar and newrelic.yml file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to reconfigure your jvmArgs like below and it works perfectly for me.

```
-javaagent:/newrelic.jar
```

My directory look like this

```
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── bin
├── build
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
├── gradlew
├── newrelic.jar
├── newrelic.yml
├── out
├── src
```

Comment: you mean my build.gradle should look like this one:- bootRun {
jvmArgs = [""-javaagent:/newrelic.jar"]
}

Comment: like this--> jvmArgs = ["-Dlog.directory=.", "-Dlog.media=STDOUT", "-javaagent:/newrelic.jar"]

Comment: How you are running your application ?

Comment: I am running my application by right clicking on my main file and running it as Java Application. It's not picking the bootRun task.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? If you're in STS -> use run as Springboot app. Otherwise try from command line -> "./gradlew bootRun" or "mvn spring-boot:run"

Comment: Hi i am able to configure it through command line >./gradlew bootRun. but in that case how it'll run on prod deployment where it's deployed as war file in tomcat.

Comment: Spring boot is predominantly used for microservices . It will be packaged as a jar typically. Single runnable unit. Gradle commands are used to run it or run the built jar. It will pick it. That's how I m using in production for more than a year.